# Why is the function name empty in exception messages in PowerShell? How to get it correctly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get script name, function name, line number and message from exception message. Except function name I am able to take others.
My code is as below

```
function dividebyzero {
    try {
        1/0
    } catch {
        throw $_
    }
}
```

The above function is in a file `ExceptionSample.Psm1`.

```
Import-Module C:\Scripts\ExceptionSample.Psm1

function Write-ErrorLog {
    Param(
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]$ErrorInfo
    )
    $formatstring = "[Script ({0}), function {1} , Line {2}, Message {3}]" 
    if ($ErrorInfo.InvocationInfo.ScriptName) {
        # this is done to correctly recieve the original error back from Pester mocks
        $scriptname = $(Split-Path -Path $ErrorInfo.InvocationInfo.ScriptName -Leaf)
    }
    $fields = $scriptname,
              $ErrorInfo.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
              $ErrorInfo.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber,
              $ErrorInfo.Exception.Message

    $formatstring -f $fields    
}

try {
    dividebyzero
} catch {
    Write-ErrorLog -ErrorInfo $_        
}
```

The output comes except for function name.

```
[Script (ExceptionSample.Psm1), function  , Line 5, Message Attempted to divide by zero.]
```

What is missing? Is there any other way to get the function name?

Comment: Don't use `try/catch` just to throw the error record.

Comment: IMHO you need to parse `$ErrorInfo.ScriptStackTrace` string to obtain  the function name.

Comment: I don't think PowerShell actually records the function name with the exception.